# Ssrs, count a filed using a wildcard

Tags: reporting-services

I want to get the count for a field in SSRS where the name begins with v.

I thought it would be like this but it doesn't work.

= count(iif(Fields!Sent.Value = "*v*",1,0))

Comment: Since you are using 1 and 0, you should use SUM instead of COUNT. Count will count a zero or a 9 as 1 thing. If you want the distinct SENT values, you'd want `=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!Sent.Value = "v", Fields!Sent.Value, NOTHING))` to count the distinct values - the Count ignores NOTHING.

Comment: Hi, so I want it to return things that start with v so something like v%, how would I achieve that?

Comment: Duh - sorry. I was focused on using the COUNT part right. SSRS uses a asterisk * as the wildcard character instead of %. `=SUM(IIF(Fields!Sent.Value LIKE "v*",1,0))`